A very difficult situation: my coauthor "scooped" my proof and theorem in a joint work
I am working in a field of math and have written some papers, some published, some not. I have one small paper finished in 2021, which I forgot to send for publication.
At the moment, I am co-authoring with some other researchers on a similar topic. In a recent update, they came-up-with some theorem very similar to my unpublished paper, with almost identical proofs.
What is the best action to exercise here? Shall I send my working paper to them?

Was my 2021 working paper circulating? Well, an old version was. That paper contained a similar theorem and a very similar proof. A newer version (2021 version) of the working paper was not circulating, and it contains exactly the same theorem.

Sounds like your theorem may finally be published with you as an author, your neglect notwithstanding. What's the issue exactly?

What precisely does "circulating" mean? Did you upload it to arXiv? Or did you just send it to a few colleagues who might have sent it to other colleagues?

Sounds like they read your old manuscript and in the meantime forgot where the idea came from. Now they used it, did some inconclusive literature research, and thought must have been our idea, lets publish before someone else does. ;)

Would you like to publish that proof in the new paper with those coauthors, or do you want to publish it on your own and get cited in that new coauthored paper?

Since there's not actual authorship dispute, I fail to see the problem. I would absolutely tell them about your old paper, but phrase it as a funny coincidence that your old, forgotten work contains a very similar proof. Don't start a priority dispute, it's pointless since you'll be an author on the paper the shows the proof anyway. Yes, you could maybe have been the sole author of a separate paper, but trying to do that now will rob your co-authors of the fruits of their labors if they did indeed find that proof independently. Creating that kind of bad blood very likely isn't worth it.

@Karl Get cited in the new paper

It would be helpful to have more information here. You ask:

Shall I send my working paper to them?

From this, I infer that your paper was not available to these co-authors before. So, they did not "scoop" you. They independently came up with the same result. In this case, it's unlikely that you can publish the result separately. You can't be an author on two different papers that prove the same exact result as a main theorem.

What is the best action to exercise here?

First, in the future, be sure to put your work on arXiv when you finish it, so that others know you proved it. Second, be sure to submit it in a timely fashion. Third, forgive yourself: remember that 2021 was a global pandemic. We all let some balls drop and that's ok. It's possible to have a successful career even if you don't manage things optimally all the time. Fourth, yes, you should send them the working paper. Your co-authors might realize that it has ideas beyond what they came up with, that could strengthen your joint paper.
Lastly, now might be a good time to check if you have other working papers floating around that you should dust off, put on arXiv, and submit for publication.

In my view, "scoop" does not imply "stolen" or anything similar, it simply means someone has beaten you to releasing something. Whether they were aware of your work or completely independent, it's still scooping. Scooping doesn't describe the fault of some other, it describes the situation someone is in when they feel they've lost out on getting credit for something they did.

Sorry for being unclear. An old version of my working paper was circulating. The paper contain similar theorem and very similar proof. A newer version (2021 version) of the working paper was not circulating, and it contains exactly the same theorem.

"independently coming up with the same result" and then they publish first is what people usually called getting "scooped" :D

@BryanKrause That's helpful to know. Clearly, I always felt like it had the connotation "stolen" but I can see most people agree with your interpretation. Glad to learn this.
